# Is there a CSS3 only Animate fadein of multiple divs?

Tags: css

I have 10 divs that are squares that I would like to sequentially fade in (staggered with a slight delay) that are float:left. Is there a way to rely only on CSS for this kind of animation without the use of javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568319/expand-circles-sequentially-using-css/33568849#33568849 (though shapes and the property that is animated are different).

Comment: The answer is to use animation delay like Harry linked. Though, depending what you want, you could also [play with some simple gradient masks like this example I created.](http://jsbin.com/taribayugi/edit?html,css,output). This could be more flexible in some cases.

Comment: animation delay looks like it is being created on a "per circle"(in my case per div basis). If I have 10, 20, 25 divs (varying number) I really don't want to have multiple "classes of -1, -2, -3, -4, etc.) Is there a cleaner way? Or if javascript absolutely must be used... what is the most elegant way?